# Backbone call a model method from the view

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone app with require where I want to add a collection inside a collection with a method inside model.
I have tried to insert the method in the collection but I can't add elements.
I'd want to make a collection of app when I click an element outside the app I want add inside my app other app in a collection.

This is my app:
Model:

```
define(['backbone', 'collections/element'],function(Backbone, ElementCollection){
    var DesignModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('Initialized Design model');
            _.defaults(this, {
                elements: new ElementCollection()
            });
        },
        addElement: function(elements, options) {
            return this.elements.add(elements, options);
        }
    });

    return DesignModel;
});
```

Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/design'], function(Backbone, DesignModel){

    var designCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DesignModel,
    });

    return designCollection;
});
```

View

```
define(['jquery' , 'backbone', 'models/design', 'collections/design', 'views/element'], 
    function($, Backbone,  DesignModel, DesignCollection, ElementView){
    var DesignView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#page'),

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('initialize DesignView');
            this.collection = new DesignCollection();
            var here = this;
            $('#insert-dynamic-element').click(function(){
                var element = new ElementView();
                here.collection.models.addElement(element); 
            });
        },
        render: function(){

        }
    })

    return DesignView;
});
```

I have tried to call the function addElement in this way:

```
here.collection.models.addElement(element);
```

and

```
here.collection.addElement(element);
```

But always with error that Object has no method addElement
How can I solve this? I want to call the method addElement from the view to add an app inside another app in a collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to call the method is to add the method to the collection instead of the Model. Currently the method is available on the Model instance .

So `this.collection.models.addElement` will not cut it

**Collection**

```
define(['backbone', 'models/design'], function(Backbone, DesignModel){

    var designCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DesignModel,
        addElement: function(elements, options) {
            return this.add(elements, options);
        }
    });

    return designCollection;
});
```

**View**

```
define(['jquery' , 'backbone', 'models/design', 'collections/design', 'views/element'], 
    function($, Backbone,  DesignModel, DesignCollection, ElementView){
    var DesignView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#page'),

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('initialize DesignView');
            this.collection = new DesignCollection();
            var here = this;
            $('#insert-dynamic-element').click(function(){
                var element = new ElementView();
                here.collection.addElement(element); 
            });
        },
        render: function(){

        }
    })

    return DesignView;
});
```

If you do not want to move the method from the current model. Then you might have to call a specific model using the index

```
here.collection.at(0).addElement(element);
```

But there might be a case when there are no model in the collection and this might lead to a error condition..

```
here.collection.at(0) && here.collection.at(0).addElement(element);
```

Comment: Yes in the other question (of some days ago) you have answer well, but not working fine because not adding element into the model

Comment: Looks like you are using the `Model inside and collection` and `Collection inside the same Model` which will lead to cyclic dependency.

Comment: Your last line works without error, but if I console.log my app, I don't see the element added...

Comment: Is always empty because addElement is never calle, I have put a console.log inside the function and doesn't appear inside console

Comment: Can you create a small working fiddle. So that we can take a look at what exactly the issue is \

Comment: Find the problem, I pass a view not a json and with the function into the collection working fine! Thanks for the help +1

Comment: Glad you could figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to get a specific model, not the array of them. This seems like an error since you'll be picking a specific model essentially arbitrarily (unless you application has semantics that support this), but this would work:

```
here.collection.at(0).addElement(element);
```

Comment: What you suggest  to change into the logic if is possible?

Comment: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addElement' of undefined

Comment: Well, normally your UI would allow the user to select the DesignModel they mean. For example, you have a list of DesignModels displayed, each with it's own "Add Element" button. Alternately, you could select one with a radio button, or something along those lines. But the general idea is widgets effecting a model show be clearly associated with that model in the UI, not to the containing collection.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the edge case when the collection is empty as @Sushanth has pointed out.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that if I use the code of Sushanth works without error, but if I console.log my app I don't see the element added inside model...

Comment: Is always empty because addElement is never calle, I have put a console.log inside the function and doesn't appear inside console

Comment: Find the problem, I pass a view not a json and with the function into the collection working fine! Thanks for the help +1